# Convert PCM file decoded with opus_demo to WAV

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-14.04, vlc, codec, opus

I downloaded the Opus codec from their [git repo](http://git.opus-codec.org/opus.git/), ran `./autogen.sh`, `./configure`, `make`, and then encoded a sample file from the [opus examples page](https://www.opus-codec.org/examples/) with `./opus_demo -e voip 48000 1 8000 -cbr -bandwidth NB -complexity 0 -forcemono speech_orig.wav speech_encoded.bit`.

I then tried to decode it with `./opus_demo -d 48000 1 speech_encoded.bit speech_48khz.wav`. When I try to play it back with VLC, it doesn't play it (it shows as playing for less than a second with no sound/feedback).

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit on a virtual machine (VirtualBox). The only link I found that was even remotely related to my problem is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16496288/decoding-opus-audio-data), which relates to something else than the `opus_demo` file.

This is the output from opus_demo shell commands:

```
$ ./opus_demo -e voip 48000 1 8000 -cbr -bandwidth NB -complexity 0 -forcemono speech_orig.wav speech_encoded.bit
libopus 1.1.1-beta-38-gfc0276f
Encoding 48000 Hz input at 8.000 kb/s in narrowband with 960-sample frames.
average bitrate:               8.000 kb/s
maximum bitrate:               8.000 kb/s
active bitrate:                8.000 kb/s
bitrate standard deviation:    0.000 kb/s
$ ./opus_demo -d 48000 1 speech_encoded.bit  speech_48khz.wav
libopus 1.1.1-beta-38-gfc0276f
Decoding with 48000 Hz output (1 channels)
average bitrate:               8.000 kb/s
maximum bitrate:               8.000 kb/s
bitrate standard deviation:    0.000 kb/s
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it! Posting what I did for future readers, in case someone has the same problem.

The problem was that the files I was passing into the encoder (`opus_demo -e`) were .wav files. The encoder strictly requires .pcm files, and the decoder strictly outputs .pcm files. In order to convert .wav files to .pcm files, I downloaded [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html) for windows, and ran the following commands:

To convert a .wav file into a .pcm file:

`ffmpeg -i input.wav -f s16le -acodec output.pcm`

To convert a .pcm file into a .wav file:

`ffmpeg -f s16le -ar 48k -ac 1 -i  input.pcm output.wav`

Comment: Very helpful.  Was confused about opus_demo's output format

Comment: Thank you so much for posting how you fixed it! Super helpful.