# How to decode OggOpus file in C++?

Tags: c++, c, decoding, opus

I'm trying to decode [this](https://psv4.userapi.com/c852336//u302747398/audiomsg/d18/b58ccbc2f7.ogg) OpusOgg file using `./opus_demo -d 48000 1 b58ccbc2f7.ogg new.wav`, but get `Invalid payload length: 1332176723`. Also, I tried to use code from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16551709/4229825) but got the same error.

However, `opusdec` utility decodes this file normally.

What am I doing wrong when I use `opus_demo`? I need to decode such files in C++, but stuck on this example.

Comment: What does this have to do with C++?  Are you trying to debug `opus_demo`?  If so, you’d need an MCVE of *its* code.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to debug `opus_demo`. I think I can take the decoding part from it but stuck with this problem while decoding my file.

Comment: The obvious difference lies between your code and that of `opusdec`. Seriously, you need to provide a [mcve], your questions as it stands is just "Hey I'm doing something I'm not telling you and it gives me an error, so what am I doing wrong?". Please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I should use https://github.com/xiph/opusfile/ for opening and decoding oggOpus files.

Answer (score 0):

OpusDemo uses a custom -very simple- container format not Ogg. You should use some other decoder sw.